# Orderer bootstrap says: CA Certificate did not have the CA attribute

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Bootstrapping of the orderer gives me the following error:

```
[orderer.common.server] Start -> PANI 003 Failed validating bootstrap block: initializing channelconfig failed: could not create channel Orderer sub-group config: setting up the MSP manager failed: CA Certificate did not have the CA attribute, (SN: f8adffbd6a2debed01cd2840f1f75cd77bfdc9c)

panic: Failed validating bootstrap block: initializing channelconfig failed: could not create channel Orderer sub-group config: setting up the MSP manager failed: CA Certificate did not have the CA attribute, (SN: f8adffbd6a2debed01cd2840f1f75cd77bfdc9c)

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore.(*CheckedEntry).Write(0xc0001b1970, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore/entry.go:229 +0x515
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).log(0xc0001382a0, 0xc00003d804, 0x10355b0, 0x25, 0xc00047bd10, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:234 +0xf6
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).Panicf(0xc0001382a0, 0x10355b0, 0x25, 0xc00047bd10, 0x1, 0x1)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:159 +0x79
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging.(*FabricLogger).Panicf(0xc0001382a8, 0x10355b0, 0x25, 0xc00047bd10, 0x1, 0x1)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging/zap.go:74 +0x60
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.Start(0x1013e09, 0x5, 0xc00054f200)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:98 +0xcd
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.Main()
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:91 +0x1ce
main.main()
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/main.go:15 +0x20
```

I have checked the CA certificate files and have the following attribute:

X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
CA:TRUE, pathlen:0

I have created the genesis block with the configtxgen pointing to the folders following the common structure

Also I am using fabric CA

EDIT 1:

So I have been creating the network instead of using the cryptogen using the fabric CA, I have followed the tutorial of fabric of how to create the certificates and this is what I have done:

```
export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$HOME/Code/dockerimages/hyperledgerfabric/fabric-ca/clients/admin

./fabric-samples/bin/fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://admin:adminpw@localhost:7054 --tls.certfiles ./tls-cert.pem

./fabric-samples/bin/fabric-ca-client register --id.name peer0.example.com --id.type peer --id.affiliation example.operations --tls.certfiles ./tls-cert.pem

export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$HOME/Code/dockerimages/hyperledgerfabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/example.com/peers/peer0

./fabric-samples/bin/fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://peer0.example.com:aTSKHAhxxrIl@localhost:7054 --tls.certfiles ./tls-cert.pem -M $FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME/msp

export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$HOME/Code/dockerimages/hyperledgerfabric/fabric-ca/clients/admin

./fabric-samples/bin/fabric-ca-client register --id.name peer1.example.com --id.type peer --id.affiliation example.operations --tls.certfiles ./tls-cert.pem

export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$HOME/Code/dockerimages/hyperledgerfabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/example.com/peers/peer1

./fabric-samples/bin/fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://peer1.example.com:ptPLWOAudqNJ@localhost:7054 --tls.certfiles ./tls-cert.pem -M $FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME/msp

export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$HOME/Code/dockerimages/hyperledgerfabric/fabric-ca/clients/admin

./fabric-samples/bin/fabric-ca-client register --id.name orderer0.example.com --id.type orderer --id.affiliation example.operations --tls.certfiles ./tls-cert.pem

export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$HOME/Code/dockerimages/hyperledgerfabric/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer0

./fabric-samples/bin/fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://orderer0.example.com:WfEfUodXgjDI@localhost:7054 --tls.certfiles ./tls-cert.pem -M $FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME/msp
```

After registering all the peers and the orderer I have started creating the artifacts with the following commands

```
export CHANNEL_NAME=examplechannel

./fabric-samples/bin/configtxgen -profile OrdererGenesis -outputBlock ./config/genesis.block -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME

./fabric-samples/bin/configtxgen -profile ExampleChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./config/channel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME

./fabric-samples/bin/configtxgen -profile ExampleChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./config/ExampleMSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg Example
```

All that using the structure of the crypto material folders like this:

```
- ordererOrganizations
    - example.com
        - msp
          - admincerts (the certificates of the administrators of that organization)
          - cacerts (the ca certificates of the organization)
          - tlscacerts (the tls certificate)
          - signcerts
- peerOrganizations
    - example.conm
        - msp
          - admincerts (the certificates of the administrators of that organization)
          - cacerts (the ca certificates of the organization)
          - tlscacerts (the tls certificate)
          - signcerts
```

EDIT 2:

So they are a couple of things. I am using fabric CA without any external certificate and TLS enabled, so, on bootstrapping it creates all the crypto material.
In order to found the issue I have been comparing decoding the material created by the cryptogen tool and the fabric ca material, I have used this web https://certlogik.com/decoder/.
All but the tls certificate has the same attributes. The one created by the cryptogen tool has the following property true:

X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
CA:TRUE

But the one created by the fabric ca has the attribute to false, so is there a property that determines this and I have not setted up or is a bug?

EDIT 3:

So thanks to @gari and also to the people on the hyperledger chat, I have come to the solution. I was mistaking the tls created by the ca, with the tlsca that are 2 separated things.

TLSCAs have to be distributed out of band.
Set up an nginx server on the ca and serve them with a real public cacert backed http request, scp them around, sneaker net, whatver
there is a hack to get it from the ca-server directly with curl but it requires turning off ca checking

A lets encrypt would do but you' need a separate nginx server or equivalient set to serve the non public tlsca. Or you can just use a LE cert for the tlsca itself, but that would suck because you'd have to redo every channel every time the tlsca was renewed from lets encrypt.

Comment: can you please explain more on how you got this error?

Comment: sure, I have specified more, if you can have a look please @RisabhSharma , ty

Comment: so after creating the msps for the admins orgs peers and admins when you you tried starting the orderer you got this error?

Comment: yes, it gave me that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that both `cacerts` and `tlscacerts` actually contain root certificates.  From how you described the layout above, it looks like you do not have CA certificate(s) is the `tlscacerts` folder.

Comment: Hi gari, thank you, I have added more information on the edit

Comment: I think you are still using the TLS certificate and not the CA which signed the TLS certificate.

Comment: yes, I have been chatting on the hyperledger chat, I have to get a tlsca signed outside of the fabric ca. Im going to copy here what I have been talking on the chat so If someone comes in the future can read it. Thanks a lot Gari